# How to check if an element is in a node.collection using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm begining with Neo4j/Cypher, I have some nodes containing a property which is an **array of integers**. I want to check if a given number is in a node's collection and if so, append this node to the results. My query looks like this:

```
MATCH (a) WHERE has(a.user_ids) and (13 IN a.user_ids) RETURN a
```

where 13 is the given user_id. It throws a syntax error:

```
Type mismatch: a already defined with conflicting type Node (expected Collection<Any>)
```

Any idea how can I accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My answer bugged me, so I looked into it a little more and have updated it with some additional thoughts in case you're interested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try the predicate ANY, which returns true if any member of a collection matches some criterion.

```
MATCH (a) WHERE has(a.user_ids) and ANY(user_id IN a.user_ids WHERE user_id = 13)
```

It looks a bit backwards now that I'm looking at it, but it should work.

**Edit:**

It was bugging me why your query didn't work and why my answer seemed backwards and indirect so I did a simple test. Basically, your original query works if you put the property reference in parentheses:

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE has(a.user_ids) and (13 IN (a.user_ids))
RETURN a
```

That's easier to read so that's what I should have answered. But I still couldn't see why the parentheses where necessary here, when they are not in other cases. They were not necessary inside the `ANY()` above, and if you 'detach' the collection from the node

```
MATCH (a)
WITH a.user_ids as user_ids, a
WHERE 13 IN user_ids
RETURN a
```

there's no problem. For some reason Cypher needs to be told to evaluate `a.user_ids` before `IN`, or it ignores `user_ids` and tries to evaluate `13 IN a`. `IN` is listed as an operator in the documentation, but in this regard it woks differently than other operators. For example

```
MATCH (a) RETURN 13 + a.user_ids
```

returns fine and

```
MATCH (a) RETURN 13 * a.user_ids
MATCH (a) RETURN 13 < a.user_ids
```

fails but because `a.user_ids` is a collection, not because `a` is a node. It's probably not very important, it's easy enough to use parentheses, but it would be interesting to learn why they are necessary.

I also compared my answer to your original query with added parentheses to see if there were any performance drawback to the more indirect way. Turns out the execution plan is almost identical, `13 IN (a.user_ids)` is refactored to use `ANY()` like in my answer.

My answer:

```
Filter(pred="any(user_id in Product(a,user_ids(6),true) where user_id == Literal(13))", _rows=1, _db_hits=8)
    AllNodes(identifier="a", _rows=8, _db_hits=8)
```

Your query + ():

```
Filter(pred="any(-_-INNER-_- in Product(n,user_ids(6),true) where Literal(13) == -_-INNER-_-)", _rows=1, _db_hits=8)
    AllNodes(identifier="n", _rows=8, _db_hits=8)
```

Finally, in your case you probably don't have to check for existence of property with `has()`. Absent properties and `null` are handled differently in 2.0 and if the property doesn't exist `13 IN (a.user_ids)` will evaluate to `false`, so usually there is no reason to test for property existence before property evaluation for fear of the query breaking. The place to use `has()` would be when property existence is relevant in itself, and that would probably be a different property than the one evaluated, i.e. `WHERE has(a.someProperty) AND 13 IN (a.someOtherProperty)`.

Since there is no performance difference, the more readable query is better, and since you, as far as I can see, don't really need to test for property existence, I think your query should be

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE 13 IN (a.user_ids)
RETURN a
```

Comment: Thank you for such a complete and pedagogical answer. I would +100 if I could. I hope that helps other people as well. Best,

Comment: `has` is no longer present in Neo4j, now it is replaced with `exists`